# Moment.js format() returns random time string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Ran into this bizarre problem. Moment.js is refusing to return anything other than "18:03" when using .format(). Here's a dump from my javascript console, the same behavior happens in code. Tried reloading page, closing Chrome, using incognito mode, nothing changes it.

Has anyone seen this before?

```
18:45:46.436 moment().format()
18:45:46.467 "2019-03-06T18:45:46+00:00"
18:45:51.239 var momentNow = moment()
18:45:51.241 undefined
18:45:58.777 momentNow
18:45:58.788 r {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: C, _d: Wed Mar 06 2019 18:45:51 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), …}
18:46:11.793 momentNow.format("HH:MM")
18:46:11.804 "18:03"
```

Comment: this is a console log, not code. but it's been answered below, incorrect formatting string.

Comment: @StevenStark, the included console log alternates code with the returned output. That's just fine.

Comment: @trincot in this case you were able to infer the code based on the filter string, that would not always be the case. Console logs prevent us from seeing the whole story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use lowercase the `m` in `hh:mm`. The upper case `M` is for the month.

Comment: Note that you can still use uppercase `HH` if you want 24-hour format instead of the 12-hour format that you get with `hh`.

Comment: Yup, you got it, thank you. That will teach me to use some php-to-moment code off github and just assume the code was correct...! Will mark correct as soon as it lets me.